# How to convert Oracle table into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the query to create a specific table in Oracle , but I need to create the exact same table in SQL Server with the same columns, settings and functions at the end:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "FRAUD_OWNER"."DR_DISKSPACE_ALL" 
(   
    "IP" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "FILESYSTEM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "DISKSIZE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "USED" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "AVAIL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "USEDPERCENT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MOUNTED" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "RUN_DATE_TIME" DATE
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
        PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "FV_DATA"  ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT ;
```

How can I achieve that or if someone can convert it to SQL Server?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "settings and functions at the end"?  If you're referring to all the storage clauses at the end (everything starting at `segment creation immediate`), it doesn't make sense to try to meaningfully translate that into SQL Server syntax.  Most of those settings have no obvious counterpart.

Comment: Please don't treat Stack Overflow like a "free coding service", it isn't one. Every dialect of SQL is different, and if you need to work with several, you need to learns the specifics of each of those dialects. Instead, you should be researching what the above settings and clauses do, and then looking up what the equivalent T-SQL syntax is; and that's if there is one as Oracle and SQL Server are very different products and have different features and underlying designs. If, however, you've got stuck with a specific clause, then ask about about that one.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't bring over any of those settings at the end.  They are mostly just Oracle defaults anyway.  So simply `varchar2` => `varchar`, and remove `BYTE` which is the only way to specify `varchar` length in SQL Server.

Oracle schemas often map to SQL Server databases, although you can map to a SQL Server schema if you like.

Also Oracle is always case-sensitive, so you might want to select a case-sensitive collation.

```
USE FRAUD_OWNER
CREATE TABLE "DR_DISKSPACE_ALL" 
(    
    "IP" VARCHAR(50), 
    "FILESYSTEM" VARCHAR(50), 
    "DISKSIZE" VARCHAR(30), 
    "USED" VARCHAR(20), 
    "AVAIL" VARCHAR(20), 
    "USEDPERCENT" VARCHAR(20), 
    "MOUNTED" VARCHAR(30), 
    "RUN_DATE_TIME" DATE
)
```

If you have lots of tables to convert, or need to convert Oracle SQL or Oracle PL/SQL code, you can use [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/getting-started-with-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SSMA%20for%20Oracle%20User%20Interface%201%20Metadata%20Explorers.,5%20Output%20Pane%20and%20Error%20List%20Pane.%20).

And you should probably add a clustered primary key.